# Can't access "v8" outside of node.js repl

Tags: javascript, node.js, buffer, v8

I needed to use the "v8" variable of node.js to serialize and deserialize some buffers. But I can't seem to access it outside of the Node.js repl. Here are some screenshots

[This is accessing v8 inside of the node.js repl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1NDgF.png)

[this is trying to access v8 inside of a file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TnNsH.png)

Are there any work arounds or ways I could use to access v8 inside of a file?

Comment: May you share the code you're using inside the file? Are you requiring V8? https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v13.x/api/v8.html#v8_v8

Comment: No sorry I didn't require it, the answer by @splatterxl fixed the problem :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`v8`, in a Node.js REPL, is a pre-defined variable that is the same as the `v8` inbuilt  **module**.

You can access the module through ES modules and CommonJS:

```js
// ES
import v8 from "v8";

// CommonJS
const v8 = require("v8");
```